# Can I have a jquery AJAX image Picker to use it as a RTE plugin

Tags: jquery, django, rich-text-editor, mcimagemanager

now i am developing a django-based blogging system. and am stuck when trying to integrate textarea with a fully-featured Rich Text Editor, tiny-MCE and CKEditor implemented their image browser (Image Manager) plugin using PHP (with a complex-not-documented source code). and when i was googling  i found that  there was a good free example from YUI

i don't need to MIX-UP YUI with jQuery. i found [WYMeditor : http://www.wymeditor.org] is a pretty good RTE but it does not have an image browser plug-in.
So, my question is if someone know about any free jquery JSON (whatever the SSS is) based image browser plugin that i can integrate it with WYMeditor, or any other jQuery RTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-tinymce integrates with django-filebrowser for image browsing

[http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/](http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/)

http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/